# Arrayadaper selected grid are changed when scroll

Tags: android, android-layout

this is my code gridview using arrayadapter ,this is getview part

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
final ViewHolder holder;

if (convertView == null) {
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.children_row_grid, null);
    holder.text_child_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.children_name);
    holder.img_child_view = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_children);
    holder.text_child_month = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_children_month);
    holder.layout_selected = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout_children_selected);

    Resources r = getResources();
    float pixels = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 150, r.getDisplayMetrics());
    int pixel_height = (int) pixels;
    /*
     * getting month value from the data of birth
     * */
    String dob = children_list.get(position).getDate_of_birth();
    Date child_birthday = null;
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    dob = dob.replace("-", "/");
    new ParsePosition(0);
    try {
        child_birthday = (Date) dateFormat.parse(dob);
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    holder.layout_selected.setId(children_list.get(position).getChild_id());
    holder.img_child_view.setId(children_list.get(position).getChild_id());
    display_month = Utill.getAgeinMonths(child_birthday);

    holder.img_child_view.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, pixel_height));
    holder.img_child_view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "imcge clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            children_count++;
            text_children_count.setText("" + children_count);

            //System.out.println("checking...."+intList.contains(v.getId()));
            System.out.println("size of array:::" + intList.size());
            if (intList.contains(v.getId())) {
                System.out.println("yes");
                System.out.println("..." + intList.contains(v.getId()));
                Integer val = v.getId();
                intList.remove(val);
                holder.layout_selected.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                intList.add(v.getId());
                System.out.println("no");
                System.out.println("..." + intList.contains(v.getId()));
                holder.layout_selected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            for (Integer value: intList) {
                System.out.println("Value = " + value);
            }
        }
    });
    convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

String grname = children_list.get(position).getGroup_name();

if (grname == null) {
    grname = "";
}
holder.text_child_name.setText(children_list.get(position).getFirst_name());
holder.text_child_month.setText(display_month + "," + grname);
Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/com.x/unChildren/" + children_list.get(position).getPhoto()), ConfigurationData.staffImageSize, ConfigurationData.staffImageSize);
holder.img_child_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

return convertView;

}
}
```

issue: when i select the grid ,i'm adding the imageview in the relative layout which working fine,here when i scroll the gridview the selected grids are changed

Comment: can you please try to move your on click listener code out side if-else and check ?

Answer (score 1):

When you recycle a view:

```
convertView != null
```

at this part:

```
 }else{
      holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
 }
```

you still need to test for conditions and replace images within the view, if they changed. A non-null convertView does not mean that it has the content in it that you expect, it just means that the processor does not have to rebuild the layouts.

In other words, you probably need to reset images, replace the onClick listener, etc. in that section of code.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove this

```
if (convertView == null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;

            if(convertView == null){
                holder=new ViewHolder();
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                        .inflate(R.layout.children_row_grid, null);
                holder.text_child_name=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.children_name);
                holder.img_child_view=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_children);
                holder.text_child_month=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_children_month);
                holder.layout_selected=(RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout_children_selected);

                Resources r = getResources();
                float pixels = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 150, r.getDisplayMetrics());
                int pixel_height = (int) pixels;
                /*
                 * getting month value from the data of birth
                 * */
                String dob=children_list.get(position).getDate_of_birth();  
                Date child_birthday = null;
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

                dob = dob.replace("-", "/");
                new ParsePosition(0);
                try {
                child_birthday = (Date) dateFormat
                .parse(dob);
                } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();            

                }



                display_month=XUtill.getAgeinMonths(child_birthday);                

                holder.img_child_view.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT , pixel_height));                          
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.layout_selected.setId(children_list.get(position).getChild_id());
            holder.img_child_view.setId(children_list.get(position).getChild_id());
            holder.img_child_view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "imcge clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    children_count++;
                    text_children_count.setText(""+children_count);                 



                    //System.out.println("checking...."+intList.contains(v.getId()));
                    System.out.println("size of array:::"+intList.size());

                    if(intList.contains(v.getId())){
                        System.out.println("yes");
                        System.out.println("..."+intList.contains(v.getId()));
                        Integer val=v.getId();
                        intList.remove(val);
                        holder.layout_selected.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    }else{
                        intList.add(v.getId());
                        System.out.println("no");
                        System.out.println("..."+intList.contains(v.getId()));
                        holder.layout_selected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }




                }
            });

            if(intList.contains(holder.layout_selected.getId())){


                holder.layout_selected.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);

            }else{

                holder.layout_selected.setVisibility(android.view.View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            String grname=children_list.get(position).getGroup_name();

            if(grname==null)
            {
                grname="";
            }

            holder.text_child_name.setText(children_list.get(position).getFirst_name());
            holder.text_child_month.setText(display_month+","+grname);
            Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/com.x/y/"+children_list.get(position).getPhoto()), ConfigurationData.staffImageSize,ConfigurationData.staffImageSize);
            holder.img_child_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            return convertView;

        }
```

Changes:

1. SetId() for layout and views after if(convertView == null) and else part
2. Change onclicklistener to after after if(convertView == null) and else part
3. Use below code :

   if(intList.contains(holder.layout_selected.getId())){

   ```
                   holder.layout_selected.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);

               }else{

                   holder.layout_selected.setVisibility(android.view.View.INVISIBLE);
               }
   ```